# Entity.entity_name.collection link missing when creating a custom entity type

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I've been trying to programmatically create a custom entity type, yet I keep getting an error message I can't seem to figure out. Here is my code:

/src/Entity/Car.php

```
namespace Drupal\car\Entity;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\BaseFieldDefinition;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityChangedTrait;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface;
use Drupal\user\UserInterface;

/**
 * Defines the Car entity.
 *
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "car",
 *   label = @Translation("Car"),
 *   handlers = {
 *     "view_builder" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder",
 *     "list_builder" = "Drupal\car\CarListBuilder",
*
 *     "form" = {
 *       "default" = "Drupal\car\Form\CarForm",
 *       "add" = "Drupal\car\Form\CarForm",
 *       "edit" = "Drupal\car\Form\CarForm",
 *       "delete" = "Drupal\car\Form\ContentEntityDeleteForm",
 *     },
 *     "route_provider" = {
  *      "html" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\Routing\AdminHtmlRouteProvider"
 *     },
 *   },
 *   base_table = "car",
 *   admin_permission = "administer site entities",
 *   entity_keys = {
 *     "id" = "id",
 *     "label" = "name",
 *     "uuid" = "uuid",
 *   },
 *   links = {
 *     "canonical" = "/admin/structure/car/{car}",
 *     "add-form" = "/admin/structure/car/add",
 *     "edit-form" = "/admin/structure/car/{car}/edit",
 *     "delete-form" = "/admin/structure/car/{car}/delete",
 *     "collection" = "/admin/structure/car",
 *   },
 * )
 */

class Car extends ContentEntityBase implements CarInterface {

  use EntityChangedTrait;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getName() {
    return $this->get('name')->value;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function setName($name) {
    $this->set('name', $name);
    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {

    $fields = parent::baseFieldDefinitions($entity_type);

    $fields['name'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('Name'))
      ->setDescription(t('The name of the car entity.'))
      ->setSettings([
        'max_length' => 50,
        'text_processing' => 0,
      ])
      ->setDefaultValue('')
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'string',
        'weight' => -4,
      ])
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
        'type' => 'string_textfield',
        'weight' => -4,
      ])
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
      ->setRequired(TRUE);

    $fields['created'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('created')
      ->setLabel(t('Created'))
      ->setDescription(t('The time that the entity was created.'));

    $fields['changed'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('changed')
      ->setLabel(t('Changed'))
      ->setDescription(t('The time that the entity was last edited.'));

    return $fields;
  }

}
```

/src/Entity/CarInterface.php

```
namespace Drupal\car\Entity;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityChangedInterface;

/**
 * Provides an interface for defining Car entities.
 */
interface CarInterface extends ContentEntityInterface, EntityChangedInterface {

  /**
   * Gets the Car name.
   *
   * @return string
   *   Name of the Car.
   */
  public function getName();

  /**
   * Sets the Car name.
   *
   * @param string $name
   *   The Car name.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\car\Entity\CarInterface
   *   The called Car entity.
   */
  public function setName($name);

}
```

/car.links.menu.yml

```
# Car menu items definition
entity.car.collection:
  title: 'Car list'
  route_name: entity.car.collection
  description: 'List Car entities'
  parent: system.admin_structure
  weight: 100
```

I also have src/CarListBuilder.php (content is irrelevant to the problem, I think)

The error I'm getting is:

Route "entity.car.collection" does not exist. in...

I checked in the router table and it looks like only four out of the five links ("canonical","add-form","edit-form","delete-form") were created but not "collection".

I inspected the code generated by Drupal console's generate:entity:content, yet I can't find in any of the code another place the collection link is defined apart from the annotation.

Also, another thing I noticed  was that there is no "car" base_table.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested with Drupal 8.6 and it worked fine for me, these are the steps I went throu:

#### Step 1. `$ drupal generate:entity:content`

```
// Welcome to the Drupal Content Entity generator
Enter the module name [aa_11]:
> mymodule

Enter the class of your new content entity [DefaultEntity]:
> Car

Enter the machine name of your new content entity [car]:
>

Enter the label of your new content entity [Car]:
>

Enter the base-path for the content entity routes [/admin/structure]:
>

Do you want this (content) entity to have bundles? (yes/no) [no]:
> no

Is your entity translatable? (yes/no) [yes]:
> no

Is your entity revisionable? (yes/no) [yes]:
> no
```

#### Step 2. `$ drupal entity-updates -y`

#### Result file: src/CarListBuilder.php

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityListBuilder;
use Drupal\Core\Link;

/**
 * Defines a class to build a listing of Car entities.
 *
 * @ingroup mymodule
 */
class CarListBuilder extends EntityListBuilder {


  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildHeader() {
    $header['id'] = $this->t('Car ID');
    $header['name'] = $this->t('Name');
    return $header + parent::buildHeader();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildRow(EntityInterface $entity) {
    /* @var $entity \Drupal\mymodule\Entity\Car */
    $row['id'] = $entity->id();
    $row['name'] = Link::createFromRoute(
      $entity->label(),
      'entity.car.edit_form',
      ['car' => $entity->id()]
    );
    return $row + parent::buildRow($entity);
  }

}
```

Comment: Cesar: generating an entity using the Drupal console works for me too. I am trying to learn Drupal 8 development and want to understand what every bit of code does. The code I pasted is something I wrote myself after reading a few resources. If you try to use my code you will see that for some reason the 'collection' link is not created in the 'router' table. I'm trying to figure out why